# kendo grid add non displayed field to store original value from valid field in datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, field, objectdatasource

I have a datasource that has a column value i want to store in another "new" field that the datasource doesn't know about or care about.
I tried using the "from:" notation when adding the field, but i get error indicating my "legal" datasource field is undefined. Code snippet is below. I am adding this line to my model in the schema section of the KendoGrid definiton.
The column that has its value supplied by datasource directly is "remQty".
Can anyone spot why I get the "remQty" is undefined error?

```
schema: {
    model: {
            id: "myid",
            fields: {
                remQty: {type: "number",editable : true},
                originalRemQty: {type: "number", from: "remQty", editable : false}               
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use `from` to copy another field.

> The option is supposed to get the value from the specified field in the raw JavaScript object and store it in a field of the model with a different name.

Source: http://www.telerik.com/forums/model---options-fields-fieldname-from-description-not-clear#3Nrb09uB5kmXOI2F3Xsbrw

Comment: I was able to use a column template and some javascript to set the column value to a calculated value, and then access it via the DOM to use in validation logic.